# Best approximation in space of continuous functions

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, banach-spaces, linear-transformations

I'm trying to solve this question:

Let $Y$ be the subspace of $C[-1,1]$ consisting of even functions.
Prove that $Y$ is closed and that for any $f\in C[-1,1]$ the function $Pf(x)=\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}$ is the unique element of $Y$ closest to $f$, i.e 
$$\text{inf}_{g\in Y}\lVert f-g \rVert=\lVert f- Pf \rVert$$

The excercise doesnt say with which norm but I think one should assume that it's the infinity norm? I know how to show that it is closed, but I don't know how to tackle the minimization problem. If I'm not mistaken, $C[-1,1]$ isn't unifomly convex with the supremum norm and there's no guarantee for a unique element satisfying the infimum. 
I'm thinking that maybe one can use polynomial approximation:

If $\mathbb{P_n}$ is the space of polynomials of degree n, project $f$ onto
$Y \cap \mathbb{P}_n$, and then use some kind of density argument.

I would be very grateful if somebody could help me with this!

Comment: For spaces $C(K)$, where $K$ is compact, always assume the norm is $\lVert f\rVert = \max \{ \lvert f(x)\rvert : x \in K\}$, unless some other norm is explicitly specified. (Just like in $\mathbb{R}^n$ one assumes the standard topology unless something else is explicitly stated). Look at the odd function $Qf = f - Pf$. Try to show that for an odd function $o$ and an even function $e$, you have $\lVert o - e\rVert \geqslant \lVert o\rVert$. The uniqueness would correspond to the assertion that equality holds _only_ for $e = 0$, but that is not the case in general.

Comment: So maybe there was a different norm intended after all. $\lVert f\rVert = \Bigl(\int_{-1}^1 \lvert f(x)\rvert^2\,dx\Bigr)^{1/2}$ would make the assertion correct.

Comment: Thank you! But with the 2-norm, the space isn't closed?

Comment: $Y$ is closed in $C[-1,1]$ also if we endow that with the 2-norm. We can't directly apply the theorems about Hilbert spaces since $C[-1,1]$ isn't complete in the 2-norm, but since we have the orthogonal decomposition $C[-1,1] = Y \oplus Y^{\perp}$, we still have unique best approximations in $Y$ and in $Y^{\perp}$.